# Selenium: cookie functionality not working

Tags: selenium

I am new to selenium. I am trying to test an application. Application has two pages login.jsp, restricted.jsp. You can access restricted.jsp, only after login (trying to access restricted.jsp without login will redirect to login.jsp page). My selenium application is like below.

a. Login to the app first

b. After successful login, store all the cookies to "session.properties" file.

c. Next time onwards, I am loading all the cookies from "session.properties" to driver and try to access "restricted.jsp" page. But I am redirecting to login.jsp, instead of restricted.jsp.

Following is my Java code.

```
public class App {

 private static void loginApp(WebDriver driver) {
    driver.get("http://localhost:8080/selenium_app/login");

    WebElement userName = driver.findElement(By.name("userName"));
    WebElement password = driver.findElement(By.name("password"));

    userName.sendKeys("admin");
    password.sendKeys("admin");

    userName.submit();
}

private static void storeSessionProps(WebDriver driver) throws IOException {
    File f = new File("session.properties");
    f.delete();
    f.createNewFile();

    FileWriter fos = new FileWriter(f);
    BufferedWriter bos = new BufferedWriter(fos);

    /* Get all the cookies and store them to session.properties file */
    Set<Cookie> cookies = driver.manage().getCookies();
    for (Cookie cookie : cookies) {
        bos.write(cookie.getName() + "=" + cookie.getValue());
        bos.newLine();
    }

    bos.flush();
    bos.close();
    fos.close();
}

private static void loadPropertiesToDriver(WebDriver driver)
        throws IOException {
    Properties properties = new Properties();
    FileInputStream fin = new FileInputStream("session.properties");

    properties.load(fin);

    Set<Object> props = properties.keySet();

    for (Object prop : props) {
        Cookie ck = new Cookie((String) prop,
                properties.getProperty((String) prop));
        driver.manage().addCookie(ck);
        System.out.println(ck);
    }
}

public static void main(String[] args) throws InterruptedException,
        IOException {
    WebDriver driver = new FirefoxDriver();

    // loginApp(driver);
    // storeSessionProps(driver);

    loadPropertiesToDriver(driver);
    driver.get("http://localhost:8080/selenium_app/restricted");
    Thread.sleep(5000);

    driver.quit();
}
```

}

When I uncomment the lines loginApp(driver);, storeSessionProps(driver); everything is fine, I am able to access restricted.jsp page, but when I ran application by commenting those and loading the cookies, I am redirecting to login.jsp page. Any help on this??

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to store all the data from your cookies, not just the names/values. Moreover, before creating a cookie, your need to load a page with a domain that will match the domain of the cookie.

This is an example to quickly store and restore the cookies:

```
Path cookiesFile = Paths.get("C:\\Temp\\cookies.txt");

WebDriver driver = new FirefoxDriver();
JavascriptExecutor js = (JavascriptExecutor)driver;

// load the domain
driver.get("https://www.google.com");

if(cookiesFile.toFile().exists()) {

    // load the cookies into the browser for the current domain
    String cookies = new String(Files.readAllBytes(cookiesFile), Charsets.UTF_8);
    js.executeScript(cookies);

    // reload the page with the injected cookies
    driver.get("https://www.google.com");
}

// save the cookies to a file for the current domain
try(PrintWriter file = new PrintWriter(cookiesFile.toFile(), "UTF-8")){
    for(Cookie c : driver.manage().getCookies()) {
        file.println("document.cookie='" + c.toString() + "';");
    }
}
```

Comment: Helpful answer, although I am curious: since, according to wikipedia, a cookie's structure is nothing but a (1) name, (2) value, and (3) attributes, what else is hiding in this cookie file that needs to be sent?  Why is it not enough to work with these key-value pairs, I wonder?